# Cycle decomposition of permutations and their powers

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am having a hard time getting the idea of cycle decomposition.
For example, how can we calculate such a large power for cycle decompositions?

> 1. Let $b = (123)(145)$, a multiplication of two cycles in $S_6$. Calculate $b^{99}$.
> 2. Find three elements $s$ of $S_9$ that satisfy $s^3 = (157)(283)(469)$.

What is the idea of cycle decomposition and powers?

Comment: At least for (1), you should just start calculating $b, b^2, b^3, \dotsc$ and you should see a pattern pretty quickly. We know that $b^n = e$ for some power $n$, so we'll have $b^{99} = (b^n)^kb^m = e^kb^m = b^m$ for some $m < n$.

Comment: Yeah, we can write $b^2$ as $(123)(145)(123)(145)$, but there is an easier way to write it. We can just look at where $b^2$ sends each element in $\{1, \dotsc, 6\}$. Let's look at $1$. Going from right-to-left in $b^2$ we look at where $1$ gets sent. First in $(145)$ we see $1 \to 4$. There is no $4$ in $(123)$ so we keep going. Next in $(145)$ the $4$ gets sent to $5$ so we have $1 \to 4 \to 5$. Then there's no $5$ in the last cycle $(123)$, so we know that $b^2$ sends $1$ to $5$. So we have something like $b^2 = (15\dots)\dots(..)$. Now we can trace over $b^2$ again to see where $5$ is sent.

Comment: I did so and got $b^5 = e$, is that correct? therefore, $b^{99} = b^4 = (1 3 2 5 4)$?

Comment: I got $b^5 = e$ also, so yes.

Comment: Great. What about the second? There are $9!$ elements in $S_9$ so obviously this manual method would not be efficient..

Comment: Still thinking about (2). :)

Comment: Hint: what happens when you cube some 9-cycle $\sigma = (1~2~3~\cdots~8~9)$?

Comment: @amcerbu, I do not know... the cycle you just gave gives back itself..

Comment: Not exactly: $(1~\cdots~9)^2 = (1~3~5~7~9~2~4~6~8)$. Then multiplying again: $(1~3~5~7~9~2~4~6~8)(1~2~3~4~5~6~7~8~9) = (1~4~7)(2~5~8)(3~6~9)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. We see know that for some $n$ we have $b^n = e$, so for some $m<n$ we can write $$b^{99} = (b^n)^kb^m = e^kb^m = eb^m = b^m$$ Finding $n$ is just a matter of calculating $b, b^2, b^3, \dotsc$ until you get $e$.
2. I figured out this one by the tried and true method of *guess-and-check*. Maybe (hopefully) $s$ can be written as a single cycle. Then we need to have $1 \to 5 \to 7 \to 1$ in three jumps, so it might look something like $(1\_\;\_5\_\;\_7\_\;\_)$. But then I need to have the same basic thing happen with $2\to8\to3\to2$ and $4\to6\to9\to4$, so it looks like just filling in the blanks will work. And alas $$(124586739)^3 = (157)(283)(469)$$ But the order I chose for $(157)$ wasn't special; it could have been $(7\_\;\_1\_\;\_5\_\;\_)$. So we get three more possibilities for $s$:
   \begin{align}
     &(124586739)^3 = (157)(283)(469) \\
     &(524786139)^3 = (157)(283)(469) \\
     &(724186539)^3 = (157)(283)(469)
   \end{align}
   There are quite a few more possibilities for $s$ if you play for a bit. I think in general when dealing with questions about $S_n$, don't be afraid to just play around and try stuff.

Answer (score 0):

This pertains to the second part of OP's question, since the first has been addressed. @Mike Pierce's solution is correct, but I'd like to motivate choosing a 9-cycle for $s$.

You're given $s^3 = (1~5~7)(2~8~3)(4~6~9)$. This is a composition of disjoint 3-cycles, so it has order 3. Thus $(s^3)^3 = s^9 = 1$, and so we're looking for some permutation $s$ of order dividing 9. We can quickly rule out $|s|=1$ and $|s|=3$, since then $s^3 = 1 \neq (1~5~7)(2~8~3)(4~6~9)$. So we conclude $s$ has order 9 – and the only permutations of order 9 in $S_9$ are 9-cycles.

Since all 9-cycles are conjugate, we can choose any particular one to play around with.

With a bit computation you can see that taking $\sigma = (1~2~3~\cdots~9)$:
$$
\sigma^3 = (1~4~7)(2~5~8)(3~6~9)
$$

Now $\sigma^3$ looks suspiciously like $s^3$. And by renaming variables appropriately – conjugating by other permutations in $S_9$ – we can find $s$.